# Add custom trigger to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to a a trigger to a dynamically created element then use event deligation to pick up the event and remove the dynamic element.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 clickable"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 display-clicks">
        <ul class="clicks">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

so lets say we have the above html within the display-clicks div the ul is appended with a list of co-ordinates clicked in the clickable div and next to each a remove button. the clickable div is populated with dynamically created spans all of which have a unique Id which is just the concatenated co-ordinates of the click. I can remove the appended li containing the co-ordinates and button using:

```
 $('.display-clicks').on('click','button',function(){
        // and this gets me the id of the dynamic span to be removed
        // from the clickable div
        var id = $(this).data('span-id');

        // this wont work
        $(id+'_span').remove();

        // neither will this
        $(id+'_span').trigger('myEvent');

        $(this).parent().remove();
        console.log(id);
  })
```

myEvent looks like this

```
   $('.clickable').on('myEvent', 'span', function(event){
       $(this).remove();
    })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$('clickable') => $('.clickable')`

Comment: yeah sorry thats just a typo .clickable is in the real code

Comment: What would the dynamically appended `html` looks like?

Comment: its just a span with an id like `<span id="439.124_span">x</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).parent().remove();`
 would remove the `this` element too, since you are removing it's parent. Therefore `id` cannot be defined and you can't select your span. Put that line at the end of the block. Also your id's cannot start with a number - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: I can see it looks that way I actually cast id to a variable before removing the parent and i can console.log it after trying to remove the span and li I will edit the question code.

Comment: also don't use digits in the start of the `id` value, you can use them after the first character - which should be a letter

Comment: very strange my code seems to work fine live but not on my dev machine sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $('.clickable').on('myEvent', 'span', function(event){
       $(this).remove();
    })
```

and your function is like this:

```
  $('.display-clicks').on('click','ul',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
        // and this gets me the id of the dynamic span to be removed
        // from the clickable div
        var id = $(this).data('span-id');

        // this works now
        $("#" + id+'_span_just_remove').remove();

        // this works too
        $("#" + id +'_span_trigger').trigger('myEvent');
  })
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ocZv95B3wBifX5zK7ob4?p=preview